# Using C#, SQL Database,How to

Tags: c#, sql

I have a small question.
I have used dateTimePicker and I have created a calendar.

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime varDate;
        varDate = dateTimePicker1.Value; 
    }
```

I have created a button called submit.
My Task is when a date is selected and the button is clicked it should display records from a database on a datagrid until the selected date.
For example if I select 12.28.2011 then it should display all the records less than that date.
I have created database connection and all. But how can we compare the dates??

Please give me some advice regarding this.
Thank you very much for your time for reading this question.

Comment: Have you tried searching google for tutorials on how to work with databases in C# .NET?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are loading all data from the DB or if you only want to load the data up to a given date from the DB.

If you go with the first approach, then you could use DateTime objects to hold your dates compare them with what ever date you have, [read more here.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime) What you gain by doing this is that you only need to use one database connection to load all data, but you have to hold it in memory and you might load way to much if you have a lot of data. This will make fast paginations for example.

If you use the second approach then you should change your SQL-query to have an where clause to prevent the DB to load any date according to your statement, [read more about sql here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). This will only give you the records that you actualy want to show, but it will force you to open more DB connections if you change dates, this will slow down pagination and such.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE dateField < @dateParameter";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, yourConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("dateParameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

or

```
var filteredList = yourFullList.Where(x=>x.date<dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

or give more information/code what you doing.